# Merge complex-analysis and cv.complex-variables?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms

We have distinct tags [complex-analysis](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/tagged/complex-analysis) and [cv.complex-variables](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/tagged/cv.complex-variables), of which the latter is the arXiv standard name.  They seem to mean the same thing.  Should they be merged?

Comment: I am not entirely sure merging these two tags is appropriate as, in principle, the tag 'complex-analysis' is supposed to be more specific than the tag 'cv.complex-variables'. In practice, though, the tag 'complex-analysis' may provide little extra information.

Comment: This was already proposed more than a year ago http://meta.mathoverflow.net/a/1087/ by Andres Caicedo. One might entertain a similar idea for [tag:real-analysis] as  commented there. That being said this extra visibility might be a good thing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have merged the tags. I didn't try to track how many experts in complex variables (whether in one or several variables) weighed in, but to my non-expert eyes the proposal seemed reasonable.

Answer (score 14):

I think they should be merged, as choosing one tag instead of the other seems to convey little information.
I think we should also add the expression "complex analysis" in the tag wiki excerpt of [cv.complex-variables](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/tagged/cv.complex-variables) for clarity so that it would read:

> Complex analysis, holomorphic functions, automorphic group actions and forms, pseudoconvexity, complex geometry, analytic spaces, analytic sheaves.

Comment: I made the tag wiki excerpt edit suggestion and it was approved.